# How to join two table column with one?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a mysql table user

```
username     name
---------   ------

u1           abc
u2           xyz
u3           mrz
```

and another is trading

```
product     price      buyer seller
---------   ------    ------ -------

antivirus   20           u1    u3     
e-book      10           u2    u1
```

I want to show as

```
product     price      buyer seller
---------   ------    ------ -------

antivirus   20           abc    mrz     
e-book      10           xyz    abc
```

My question is how to join these two tables ?and how to show data as if i echo as  row['name'] it will show the same name both for buyer and seller ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work :**

Use **Inner Join**

```
 SELECT t1.`product` AS `product`,t1.`price` AS `price`,t2.`name` AS `buyer`,t3.`name` AS `seller` FROM trading t1
JOIN user t2 ON t2.`username`=t1.`buyer`
JOIN user t3 ON t3.`username`=t1.`seller`
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: It works when a  user is buyer and seller but for me it is not needed that the user name should match both for buyer and seller.I have updated my post.

Comment: @user2252617, I Updated my answer please check now. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ll answer here at your last reply as it won't indent properly.

```
$result=mysql_query($query); // get the query

if(!$result){
    // if fails, do your things..
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // get data, i.e: print it ALL ROWS!
    echo $row['seller'];
    echo $row['price'];
    // and more...
}
mysql_free_result($result); // free the resource.
```

If i did not misunderstand you, that way you can work with them values.

Comment: Do not encourage people to use _mysql_*_ as it's **deprecated and will be removed** in future versions of PHP.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT t.product AS product, t.price AS price, u1.name AS buyer, u2.name AS seller
FROM trading t 
JOIN user u1 ON(t.buyer=u1.username) 
JOIN user u2 ON(t.buyer=u2.username);

Comment: This should work, but you may want to explain why this works in a few words.

Comment: what will happen when i have 1000 users like u1 .... u1000 should i query like u1.name as buyer .... u1000 as seller ?

Comment: No, u1 and u2 are distinct names for the same table you are joining twice, you are supposed to retrieve the data from the first table trading and then join it with the table user so you get the buyer, the other join with user its for retrieving the seller.

 You can't do it all in one single join basically because you will never find a buyer that bought something from himself.

Comment: how to echo these values?this way row['seller'],row['buyer'],row['price']?

Comment: @user2252617 There are billion tutorials and examples online on how to achieve it. Use PDO or mysqli.